# Select Count and Then Order By

Tags: mysql

I am having some problems trying to find the members with the most referrals.. I have been looking up stuff and trying stuff for more than 3 hours so this is my last resort. My goal is to list the members username and the amount of referrals they have..

So each members referral is marked by their id.. 
so in the example test2 is orig's ref. So each persons ref is marked by their id.

```
id | username  | ref
1  | orig      |0 (for none) 
2  | test2     |1 (orig id)
3  | another   |1 (orig id)
```

and the goal is to echo this out. If it is even possible.

```
UserName |  Refs
test        1
test2       0
```

my attempt. It gives me the amount but it does not order them and echoes to many.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
echo '<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><th>Credits</th><th>Username</th></tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $contest_id = $row['id'];

  $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE ref=".$row['id']."");  
  while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))  
  {  

  $result_c = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY ".$row1['COUNT(*)']."+0 DESC Limit 10");
  while($row_c = mysql_fetch_array($result_c))
  {
  $top_id = $row_c['id'];
  $find_c = mysql_query("select count(*) from members where user_id='$top_id'");
  $found_c =  mysql_result($find_c,0);
  echo '<tr><td>';
  echo $found_c;
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td>';
  echo $row_c['username'];
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  }}}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Why is `ref` not numeric?

Comment: Should `ref` be interpreted as `referredBy` or the other way around?

Comment: After your edit, the output should probably state "2" for user "test"? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Can you fix your expected output to match the input table? There's no `test` username in the input. And why aren't `orig` and `another` in the output?

Comment: Please don't edit your question like this... The tick mark next to an answer clearly marks your question as answered.

Comment: Leave your question body visible for future visitors, in case they have the same problem that you do.

Comment: @user2777747 when you get an answer don't edit your question to remove the content, it should be kept for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your table lay-out correctly, this should do the trick.

```
SELECT t1.username, t2.numref
FROM members t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ref, COUNT(ref) as numref
           FROM members
           GROUP BY ref) t2
ON t2.ref = t1.id
ORDER BY numref DESC
```

It should provide a `NULL` value in the `numref` column for the users that haven't made any referrals.

For reference, I added a [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9540/8/0)!

Comment: there is only one table I accidently posted the wrong attempt.

Comment: I just noticed in your SQL-Fiddle thats is amazing I got it to echo the username is the correct order but how do I echo the refs?